# Is my understanding of the AWS Lambda serverless architecture correct?

Tags: aws-lambda

I am considering to use the AWS lambda serverless architecture for my next project. This is my understanding of the technology and I would very much appreciate it if somebody can correct me.

- You can deploy function that acts as the event handlers.
- The event handlers are configured to respond to any events that are provided
- In the case of writing the lambda functions in Javascript, you can require any other Javascript modules you write and use them.
- All your lambda and its required modules are written stateless. Your app's states are ultimately kept in the database.

If you ever want to write some stateful logic such as keeping the results from one HTTP request and temporarily store it somewhere and look it up in the subsequent request, is this not possible in Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question, lambdas can use a temporal directory `/tmp` to storage files. This has a limitation of 500MB. Since the lambda container COULD be reused for performance, there is a chance that the file is still there for the next lambda invocation. This is discouraged but in some particular cases could be helpful. Anyway, if you really need it, the better approach would be to use a cache system.

In addition to your considerations, AWS Lambdas are not good for:

- To keep state, like files that are downloaded and could be reused later.
- Handle OS
- Long running tasks
- Hard latency requirements apps.
- Depending on the database client, multiple concurrent lambdas can lead to an overhead in the database connections since a client is instantiated for each lambda.

Comment: Use of the /tmp folder seems to be unreliable way to keep states. What do you mean by cache system? Like stored in a variable that is somehow persisted across different lambda calls?

Comment: Yes, it's completely unreliable but some times you just want extra easy to go burst. By cache system I mean Amazon ElastiCache or Hazelcast. Depending on your use case maybe its interesting to look into Amazon Step Functions that allows you to create finite state machines with AWS Lambdas.

Comment: Thank you RoberMP. So what step function solves is exactly what I was worried about. If I run into a requirement where I have to coordinate multiple lambda functions... I couldn't figure out how to do it. So essentially you can maintain some execution context states inside the step functions and pick and choose what stateless lambda functions to execute when. This is correct?

Comment: Yes. This article helps me a lot. Check the `state transition logic` section: https://www.stackery.io/blog/serverless-state-machines/

Comment: This is truly magical stuff. Thank you. I feel like this is the future of building complex and scalable application servers for sure.